# Ansi color sequences from vim bleeding into prompt in GNU Screen

Tags: colorscheme, gnu-screen

So, when running vim under gnu screen and using a color scheme, some of the color sequences bleed into the prompt after I close the program. This only happens under gnu screen, and not when I'm not running a terminal multiplexer. It also doesn't happen under tmux FWIW.

I'm not sure whether GNU screen or vim is the culprit here. Other editors that use colors like jed, joe and gnu emacs do not leave stray colors.

How do I configure either screen or vim to not do this?

Steps to reproduce and visual proof:

Sorry if the screenshots take up a lot of space, I can cut it down, but I think this makes the problem obvious.

1) start gnu screen

[image]

2) start vim

[image]

3) this is vim without any color scheme turned on.

[image]

4) turn on the industry color scheme (note that the filetype plugin is not on, so the whole thing is bright white).

[image]

5) exit vim and hit enter a couple of times

[image]

Comment: What is `echo $TERM` here? Also, what does `:set term?` report in Vim?

Comment: `TERM` is set to `screen-bce` (`defbce on` in my `.screenrc` is a workaround for another bug) vim's `:set term` is `term=screen-bce` ... so it looks like vim is picking up the terminal type from the environment correctly. Whether it knows what to do with a `screen-bce` terminal is anyone's guess.

Comment: Maybe this topic will help you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15279464/1199156

Comment: Does pressing `<C-l>` fix it?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker inside vim or in the shell? For the moment, I'm working around the problem by using color codes in my shell prompt, which resets the color.

Comment: Inside the shell after the problem occurs. This should reset the terminal and generally fixes these sort of problems. It's not a "true" fix though.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker <C-l> does clear the previous commands but it doesn't affect the highlighting.

Comment: Which terminal emulator are you using? I can't reproduce this issue with xterm.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I'm using iterm2 on OS X with GNU Screen and a screenrc that defines background color erase.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem when messing with my VIMRC file. Seems that these `let` lines were causing the trouble, commenting them fixed the problem.

Hopefully it helps someone stumbling into this same problem.

```
"" Theme and colors   
set termguicolors

"let &t_8f="\<Esc>[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
"let &t_8b="\<Esc>[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
```